# how to calculate the trend of a specific activity

Tags: mysql, analysis, data-warehouse

I have a table in mysql which contain posts/entries, these posts have creation date and categorized. What I want to do is get the trends of those categories, each category how is the trend in the past hour? by trend, I mean, the trend of posting.

Comment: Do you just want to query your database?  If so, you'll need to post more information about the data model before anyone can help.

Comment: What does "trend" mean? Highest number of total posts in the last hour? New posts? Percentage increase in total posts? And what is your question exactly? Since you have timestamps for each post, then counting posts within a given time period is easy. So I'm not sure what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked your question with the data-warehouse tag, you should probably have 2 dimensions.  A date dimension for the day and then a time dimension for the hour, minute, seconds component of a date.  If you have those two piece, you can simply run a query joining up your time dimension to your main fact grouping by hour.

```
select pc.category, t.hour, count(*)
from post_details pc, -- since you said they were categorized
posts p,
time_of_day t
where p.time_of_day_id = t.time_of_day_id
and p.post_details_id = pc.post_details_id
group by pc.category, t.hour;
```

Even if you don't have everything dimensionalized, you still should be able to extract the hour of the date the entry was posted and do a group by.

```
select p.category, extract(hours from p.post_date), count(*)
from posts p;
```